# Vashti was never Killed

Tags: sources-mekorot, megillat-esther

I was told that the Chacmie Tzarfas said that Vashti was never killed. Does anyone have a source for this view in a shiur or inside?

[Rashi (Esther 1:19)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16474/showrashi/true#v19) says that she was executed.

Comment: In addition to the Rashi you cite in your question, Rashi to [Esther 1:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.1.12?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Esther.1.12&lang2=bi) also says she was killed: > **וַתְּמָאֵן הַמַּלְכָּה וַשְׁתִּי.** רַבּוֹתֵינוּ אָמְרוּ: לְפִי שֶׁפָּרְחָה בָהּ צָרַעַת **כְּדֵי שֶׁתְּמָאֵן וְתֵהָרֵג**. לְפִי שֶׁהָיְתָה מַפְשֶׁטֶת בְּנוֹת יִשְׂרָאֵל עֲרֻמּוֹת וְעוֹשָׂה בָהֶן מְלָאכָה בַּשַּׁבָּת, נִגְזַר עָלֶיהָ שֶׁתִּפָּשֵׁט עֲרֻמָּה בַּשַּׁבָּת: > **Queen Vashti refused.** Our Rabbis said because leprosy broke out on her, **so that she should refuse and be executed.** Because she would forc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be found on page 5 of [this pdf](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/peroshim/peroshim02.pdf) of "Kadmonim Tzarfatim" (linked from [this page](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=378)).

> ומה היא הגזירה שיגזור עליה? "אשר לא תבא ושתי לפני המלך אחשורוש", שכשם שמיאנה לבא בדבר המלך אשר ביד הסריסים, כן לא תבוא עוד לפניו. **וכל האומר שקצוה משפט מות טועה הוא בפשוטו של מקרא**, שאם הרגוה מה צורך לכתוב דבר זה בדתי פרס ומדי שלא תיבטל לאחר שיהרגהה?

Comment: Key point in translation -- if she's dead, why are they passing a law that she'll never be received again in the palace?

Answer (score 3):

The midrash suggesting that she was executed has never convinced me for these reasons :

1. It is not written anywhere in the text that she was executed. The royal edict only stated that  : « *Vashti shall never enter the presence of King Ahasuerus. And let Your Majesty bestow her royal state upon another who is more worthy than she.* » (Esther 1 :19). In the same book, the order to execute Haman is explicit and unequivocal : “*Impale him on it!” the king ordered. So they impaled Haman on the stake which he had put up for Mordecai, and the king’s fury abated.* (Esther 7) Moreover, the clarification that the decree „*cannot be abrogated*“ has no meaning for a death sentence…
2. Vashti should have been punished in line with her transgressions, „*measure for measure*“. Now, the sins attributed to Vashti are:

a) She had "*sinful intentions*" (seduce other men) so she received the just punishment when Gabriel "*disfigured her countenance*" so that she could no longer seduce anyone.

b) She stripped Jewish girls naked. *Therefore, it was decreed that she be brought before the king naked and / or be stripped of the crown.*

c) She Misbehaved as queen, preventing the rebuilding of the temple and was punished with the loss of the crown. *She told him: “You wish to rebuild what my forefathers destroyed?” She was therefore punished by the loss of her crown* (Esth. Rabbah loc. cit.; Midrash Panim Aherim [ed. Buber], version B, para.

But, among the sins that the midrash ascribes to Vashti there is not murder, so I think punishing her with death would not be "measure for measure".

Answer (score 1):

The חכמי צרפת are not the only ones with that pshat.
First, however, the full quote for the חכמי צרפת would be:

> מה היא הגזירה שיגזור עליה? "אשר לא תבא ושתי לפני המלך אחשורוש", שכשם
>   שמיאנה לבא בדבר המלך אשר ביד הסריסים, כן לא תבוא עוד לפניו. וכל האומר
>   שקצוה משפט מות טועה הוא בפשוטו של מקרא, שאם הרגוה מה צורך לכתוב דבר זה
>   בדתי פרס ומדי שלא תיבטל לאחר שיהרגהה, דבר זה אין להשיב מפני שום פיוס.
>   **אבל אין משיבין על דברי אגדה**

Emphasis added. I think that is a very relevant part of the quote.

However, that is not the only perush that learns Vashti was not killed.

The רי"ד writes:

> ומלכותה יתן המלך: ולפי הפשט לא מצאנו שהרגוה

The ר"מ חלאיו writes:

> אשר לא תבוא  ושתי לפני המלך אחשורוש: פירושי שיגרשנה  מן המלכות ולא תהיה
>   עוד גברת ולא תתראה  עוד לפניו ולא מצאנו שהרגה כללי ואין משיבין  בהגדה
>   וקבלת רבותינו ז"ל דברי אלהים חיים  (ירמיה כג לו) עכ"ל

Comment: אַ חַ ר, הַ דְּ בָ רִ ים הָ אֵ לֶּ ה, כְּ שֹׁ ךְ , חֲ מַ ת
הַ מֶּ לֶ ךְ אֲ חַ שְׁ וֵרוֹ שׁ--זָכַ ר אֶ ת-וַשְׁ תִּ י

Comment: sounds like she was dead

Comment: That just says he remembered her. It may not have befitted him to change his mind. Or, more likely, once she hand been banished - written into the laws of Persia and Media that she not appear before the king - it was irreversible. Like we see later in the megillah, a decree issued with the king's signet could not be reversed, even by the king.

Comment: can you spell out the acronyms

Comment: @nagah making up a pshat that she was banished doesn't sound more plausible in the pashut pshat than sayingshe was killed. We could apply the Tzarfatist's own logic: who needs a decree to listen to a husband once the wife has been banished?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer an indirect answer to this question...

It is never mentioned that she was killed in the Megillah. The Ibn Ezra ([1:1 on the megillah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Esther.1.1.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) writes that Mordechai wrote the megillah and omits G-d's name in order to avoid the extant Kings replacing Hashem's name with the name of their gods:

> המגילה חברה מרדכי וזה טעם וישלח ספרים וכולם משנה ספר אחד שהוא המגילה כטעם פתשגן והעתיקוה הפרסיים ונכתבה בדברי הימים של מלכיהם והם היו עובדי עבודה זרה והיו כותבין תחת השם הנכבד והנורא שם תועבתם כאשר עשו הכותים שכתבו תחת בראשי' ברא אלהים ברא אשימא **והנה כבוד השם שלא יזכרנו מרדכי במגילה.**

Rabbi Normann Lamm (although not mentioning this Ibn Ezra) has a [sermon in a similar vein](https://archives.yu.edu/gsdl/collect/lammserm/index/assoc/HASH0186/0950d4cf.dir/doc.pdf). He notes that Mordechai wrote the megillah with "divrei shalom ve'emet" (a quote directly from the Megillah). The 'shalom' aspect was to appease King Achashverosh. To this end Mordechai describes at length the extravagant party laid out by Achashverosh (the word mishteh featuring in Esther 17 out of the 34 times it features in the whole Tanach). Mordechai always protrays Achashverosh as passive and meek, and certainly not as a 'murderer of the queen'. Were Mordechai to have written a stark, fact filled, blow by blow account it would not have engendered the 'shalom' necessary to maintain the Jewish community in galut (under a non-Jewish king). Rabbi Lamm gives a few more examples, noting that Achashverosh is placed at the centre of the story without actually doing... much. The style of the Megillah is 'apologetic'.

He sums up by saying:

> The  Book  of  Esther  is,   indeed,   the  story   of   *hastir*. Megillat   Esther,   the   document  of   divvrei  shalom  ve'emet,  words  of  peace   and  truth,  is   most  appropriate   to   our  own day.    For  we,  not  only  one  day  a  year,  but  throughout  the  twelve  months,  live   a life   of  Purim.    You will  recall  that  the   derivation   of  the  word  "Purim"  is   from  the  *pur*,  the  lots  that   Haman  threw.  Purim   therefore   means  "fateful  days"    and  in  these  fateful   days,  with   the   imminent threat  of   cosmic  catastrophe,  all   human beings,   but especially   Jews,   must  learn  the  two  lessons   of   the   Book of  Esther.     They  are,  first,   that  we  must  seek  to  accomodate   the  principles   of   shalom and  emet;  that  is possible   for   them   to  co-exist,  to   maintain  the  integrity  of   emet  or  truth,   and  at  the   same  time  live   a  life   of shalom  or  peacefulness.

I understand this may not be a popular approach. But, it is at least an indirect answer, showing that Mordechai had to invoke shalom when writing the Megillah; including not making explicit mention of Vashti's capital punishment.

Comment: The OP didn’t ask why the Megillah doesn’t say that she wasn’t executed. He asked for a source that she *actually* wasn’t executed.

Answer (score 0):

It is said in the name of The Targum Simcha; The royal decree of King Achashverosh was that Vashti should be banished from his presence and should not be brought before the king anymore.

The Targum explains that a husband banishing his wife or choosing to dissociate from her, such was the case by achashverosh, is akin to death.

This can be understood why Rashi chooses to determine that she was killed even though the simple pshat of the megillah itself does not suggest that.